# OpenGL Mipmaps and SOIL Flag

Tags: opengl, mipmaps, soil

So i got the SOIL loading my images now, but it says you can set a flag for
the MipMap generation.  I set the flag and as far as I know OpenGL does the
rest when it comes to using the MipMaps at certain times.

Am I wrong in this? and if I am, how do I get the MipMaps to work?

EDIT:  So this is my init function where I call SOIL to load my image with the FLAG for MIPMAPS

```
//========================================
//  init
//========================================
void init(void) {

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glEnable(GL_NORMALIZE);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHTING);
    glEnable(GL_LIGHT0);
    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glEnable (GL_BLEND); //transparency
    glBlendFunc (GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

    timerSpeed = 1000.0/60.0;

    for(int i=0; i<6; i++) {

        TextureNames[i] = TextureNames[i]+".bmp";
        TextureArray[i] = SOIL_load_OGL_texture((char*)TextureNames[i].c_str(),3,
                                                SOIL_CREATE_NEW_ID, 
                                                SOIL_FLAG_POWER_OF_TWO |
                                                SOIL_FLAG_MIPMAPS);


    }

}
```

And this is where I call bindtexture and texparam (cut it short because its just the other
faces of the cube, popmatrix and end } for the function

```
void drawCube(void) {

    glPushMatrix();

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, TextureArray[1]);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
        glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);   

        //FRONT FACE OF CUBE
            glNormal3f(0.0,0.0,1.0);
            glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0,0.0);  glVertex3f(-1.0,-1.0,1.0);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0,0.0);  glVertex3f(1.0,-1.0,1.0);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0,1.0);  glVertex3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0,1.0);  glVertex3f(-1.0,1.0,1.0);
            glEnd();

        //LEFT FACE OF CUBE
            glNormal3f(-1.0,0.0,0.0);
            glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0,0.0);  glVertex3f(-1.0,-1.0,-1.0);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0,0.0);  glVertex3f(-1.0,-1.0,1.0);
            glTexCoord2f(1.0,1.0);  glVertex3f(-1.0,1.0,1.0);
            glTexCoord2f(0.0,1.0);  glVertex3f(-1.0,1.0,-1.0);
            glEnd();
```

Comment: Why are you passing 3 instead of SOIL_LOAD_RGB?

Comment: Hey sorry for the late response RTS, it has been some time since I was messing around with this, but if I recall correctly placing a number in like the does the same thing as calling SOIL_LOAD_RGB.  I could be wrong but I think it was something along those lines!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to switch texture filtering to use mipmapping:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, theTextureID);
glTexParamteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR);
```

You also may want to look into anisotropic filtering modes for increased filtering quality: http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/texture_filter_anisotropic.txt

Comment: Hmm.. well I do 

glBindTexture
glTexParamteri

but I do them when I call the texture to apply it.

Comment: Please if you get a chance to look at my Edit above and maybe I'm doing something utterly wrong. (The code above does load the image fine, but the mipmapping doesn't happen)

Comment: Bah, nevermind! Had to set both MIN_FILTER and MAG_FILTER to use GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR!